# Why won't my motherboard accept more than 24GB?

Tags: memory, motherboard, bios, hardware-failure

I have an ASUS Z8PE-D18 mobo, and I'm having a difficult time getting the RAM to work. Try as I might, I can't get more than 24gb in there at any given time. All of the RAM is the same and I'm using Hynix 4GB 2Rx4 PC3 PC3-10600R-9 RAM.

I've populated the RAM slots according the the instructions in the manual. I've systematically tested every slot (that the population staggering allows for), and every DIMM, and they all work, But for some reason as soon as I have more than 3 on either processor (Dual Intel Xeon X5650), they get rejected on boot. If I pull one of the older DIMMs, the wone I just put in works fine. It sure seems like I'm rubbing up against a system limitation but 128GB is supposed to be the max, and I'm only using 44GB.

I posted this question earlier (with a lot less detail, sorry about that), and some said that there might be a certain increment that the RAM gets recognized at, which is a good guess, but if that were the case, 20gb shouldn't work, and it does. I've seen 1 other person on the internet with the same issue, and they gave up and RMAd the board. I don't have that option.

Here are my BIOS settings. I'd really appreciate any help you guys can give me.

[image]
[image]

Comment: You didn't mention how much RAM you are installing and what is their specs. (Number of modules, module generation and frequency.) All of these are important.

Comment: The board itself seems to be geared towards 24GB RAM increments (3x8GB sticks). Is this what you are attempting? Other possible increments  might be 6 (3x2GB) or 12 (3x4GB), but that's a bit of a guess.

Comment: @EUserNameError 
Ok. I've included the ram type.
The frequency is currently set to 1333mhz
I'm relatively certain that it's RDIMM

Comment: sure, HYNIX HMT351V7BMR4C-H9

Comment: And I'd be fine with 24gb on wither proc, that's actually what I was shooting for, but it still doesn't explain my issue.

Answer (score 3):

From the [manual](https://www.asus.com/Commercial-Servers-Workstations/Z8PED18/HelpDesk_Manual/) only registered memory with single or dual ranks can utilize all of the DIMM slots. Unregistered and quad ranked memory can only use 6 of the 9 DIMMs. So if you're using 4GB unbuffered memory you can only have 6 of them or 24GBs.

The manual also explains how to make best use of the banks in a staggered configuration. (there are technically 3 banks per CPU with 3 DIMMs per bank). This is where you get your limitation because each bank can only have 2 DIMMs per bank when the memory is unbuffered instead of 3.

Comment: I've read the manual. RAM is staggered according to it's instructions. I thought my ram was buffered. I've edited my question and included the RAM make and type. Is it unbuffered?

Comment: HYNIX HMT351V7BMR4C-H9 is dual rank registered memory. One or more of the rams could be defective or this RAM is out of spec and is taking to much current.

Comment: I've tested each DIMM individually in known good slots. I will try undervolting the RAM to test your second theory. The manufacturer's list recommended this ram in particular, and the one other instance I saw of this issue (the guy who RMAd) was using a different brand w/ different specs. Do you think lowering the speed of the ram would have any effect?

Comment: @Enoch Root Yes, it could very well help. Although the specs are right this shouldn't be happening which implies something is defective or out of spec.